# how to strore data after jquery prepend event on twig view symfony 3?

Tags: jquery, twig, symfony

i have a problem when i click to post button i want data appeared in my page without refreshing page and add to that i want to store those data on my db and the next time i visit this page i find those data

```
    <form method="post">
                    <textarea id="txt" class="form-control input-lg no-border" rows="2"
                              placeholder="What are you doing?..."></textarea>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#btnpost").click(function () {
                    var text = $('#txt').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '{{ path('group_addpub') }}',
                        data: {desc: text}
                    });
                    $("#publication").prepend('<div class="panel panel-success rounded shadow" style="text-align: left;margin-bottom: 5px;">' +
                            '<div class="panel-heading no-border">'+
                            '<div class="pull-left half">'+
                            '<div class="media" style="text-align: left;">'+
                            '<div class="media-object pull-left" style="margin-top: 35px;">'+
                            '<img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png" style="width: 40px;height: 40px;">' +
                            '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<a href="">test profile</a>'+
                            '<span class="text-white h6" style="display: block; color: black;">on 8th June, 2014</span>'+
                            '<br>'+
                            '<span style="color: black;margin-bottom: 10px;word-break: break-all  ">'+text+ '</span>'+


                            '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="panel-footer">'+

                            '<form action="#" class="form-horizontal">'+
                            '<div class="form-group has-feedback no-margin">'+
                            '<div style="text-align: right;margin-top: 32px;">'+
                            '<a href=""><img src="{{ asset('Groupe/img/like-icon.png') }}" style="width:5%;"></a>'+
                            '<a href="" ><img src="{{ asset('Groupe/img/Unlike-icon.png') }}" style="width:5%;"></a>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Votre commentaire ici..." style="width: 95%;margin-left: 10px;">'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '</form>'+
                            '</div>');


                    $('#txt').val('');

                });
            });
        </script>

    </form>
```

this is my controller action

```
   public function addpubicationAction(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->isMethod('post') ) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $des = $request->get('txt');

        $publication = new Publication();
        $publication->setDescription($des);
        $em->persist($publication);
        $em->flush();
    }



}
```

this is my routing file

```
  group_group_photos:
path:     /photos
defaults: { _controller: GroupGroupBundle:Group:photosGroupe}

  group_new:
path:     /{id}
defaults: { _controller: GroupGroupBundle:Group:newGroupe}

 group_addpub:
path:     /addpub
defaults: { _controller: GroupGroupBundle:Group:addpubication}
```

Comment: is there someone who could help me

Answer (score 2):

You have the pieces, now just hook them up correctly.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{ path('group_addpub') }}", // NOTE the " instead of '.
    data: {desc: text} // You'll access the text variable by it's property name, 'desc'.
});
```

### In your controller:

```
public function addpubicationAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $des = $request->get('desc'); // <-- Here is the text variable.

    $publication = new Publication();
    $publication->setDescription($des);
    $em->persist($publication);
    $em->flush();
}
```

### Side note re: mixing single quotes and double quotes:

`'{{ path('group_addpub') }}'` The problem here is that when Twig parses this, it sees `'string'variable'string'` which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: what should i do to url

Comment: @Was'SiimBenHssen try setting the AJAX `url: '/addpub'`, then in your controller add `dump($request->request); die;` to see what your controller is receiving. [Open the Chrome Dev Tools network tab and view the response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39889082/how-can-we-view-symfony-dump-output-with-ajax-request).

Comment: nothing appears it seems that my controller didnt receive the data

Comment: @Was'SiimBenHssen, what's the full path to this controller action? Is the GroupBundle prefixed with `/group/addpub`?

Comment: Try changing it to `url: '/groupe/addpub',`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135520/discussion-between-rhono-and-wassiim-ben-hssen).